# Vocabulary in EDA

Tags: exploratory-data-analysis

I've found myself straggling to find appropriate vocabulary to describe a scatterplot as part of exploratory data analysis.

I've found this paper about the [graph theory](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4187799_Graph-theoretic_scagnostics?enrichId=rgreq-9768c33199e7dd23e83e04c145b6c48a-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzQxODc3OTk7QVM6MjY5MjgwOTA2MzEzNzI5QDE0NDEyMTI5Nzk0NDE%3D&el=1_x_2&_esc=publicationCoverPdf) and although it's interesting I'm not sure what vocabulary I can use

In this plot, can I say that the blue points are higher compared to orange? I don't have a model, I don't know interactions, confounders or I haven't done error control to say that the one is higher than the other.
[image]

Comment: _In this plot, can I say that the blue points are higher compared to orange_ I think this is a bit too vague. Higher concerning what (average, median, variance)? Furthermore, there are two variables under comparison. If you are looking for a comparison regarding central tendency, then a boxplot for each variable is a better choice.